# context.savechanges() not updating database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**object passed to add() and then savechanges() do not update database.**

**But, written sql query does update the database**

--I am new to mvc , didnt knew what could possibly cause the glitch so attaching all relevant screen-shots.

--please help ------->>>>>>>       [SCREEN SHOT LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NVhH.png)

Comment: add your code into the question

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: **1/.** Inside talking about your problem, you should add the code what you've tried. **2/.** When you're getting any problem, you can show us: what's the error message? Or where are you stuck?

Answer (score -1):

you should set Entry State = Modified like the below :-

```
db.Entry(personalDetail).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: No, adding an entity through `DbSet<T>.Add()` already sets the proper EntityState (which in this case isn't Modified).